# How to run the ansible-playbook command in background?

Tags: ansible, salt-stack

I can run the `salt state.sls` command in background by use `--async` parameter. Now I want to change the sls to ansible playbooks, but I can't find the parameter to make the `ansible-playbook` command run in background.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the Linux shell to background the task. Run the playbook command then hit ctrl+z to background it. Type fg to bring it back. Or you can find `ansible-playbook ... &` to run it in the background. Pair with `>>` to redirect stdout.

Comment: Yes. Now I use nohup to achieve my goal, like this:

nohup ansible-playbook main.yml >/dev/null 2>&1 &

But this is not I want .

Comment: What other properties (i.e. output stdout to file, easily bring to foreground, pause) do you want from a background process?

Comment: Actually,  I want to write a simple auto deploy program use ansible-playbook, cause the ansible tower is too hard to use for me ... The ansible-playbook  command results could saved by ansible callback plugins, so I don't need the stdout ...

Comment: i am not much familiar with saltstack, but trying to understand your problem. So you want to run ansible-playbook in background all the time and it keeps looking for serving some sort of request and when any request comes, ansible-playbook run against it. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Random_Automation yes, this is what I want to do, It was achieved through 'nohup ... &' and ansible callback plugin

Answer (score 0):

I run a long ansible-playbook always inside a [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Overview)

If you do not want to use a screen, you can prepend the command with a `nohup` and then `disown` it:

```
$ nohup ansible-playbook .... & 
$ disown
```

The `disown` command makes sure that the command doesnt hold the shell as a parent process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[tmux][1]` sessions for running the processes in the background.

1)Install the tmux package mentioned.

2)For initiating, create a new session with `tmux new -s "process_name"`.

3)Execute the process, which is required to be run in the background.

4)Detach from that session to continue other tasks, `"ctrl+B" D`.

5)Check the progess of the process by attaching again to the session,  `tmux a -t "process_name"`.